# Browsers caching my old images

Tags: html, .htaccess, caching

I am trying to prevent browsers from caching a static HTML/CSS website (the images on the site to be more specific).

So far I’ve used the solutions below, **however** some browsers/users have already cached the site before these changes occurred so they’re currently still looking at the previous version.

**Is there a way to fix this (other than telling them to force refresh)?**

Thank you!

**- CSS versioning:**

```
<link href="css/style.css?ver=4.1.0" rel="stylesheet">
```

**- Cache Control Tags in my HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

**- .htaccess Expires Headers for now** (I know this is going to slow down the site)

```
# BEGIN Gzip
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
# END Gzip

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 seconds"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES
```

Comment: if they've cached it and are refusing to validate the cache, there's very little you can do. you'll just have to wait for those browsers to expire their cache and fetch fresh copies.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured a way around it. Temporarily redirected the site to a subfolder with the same files (the updated ones to prevent caching). I'll probably leave it like this for a couple of weeks then switch back to root.